# In R, trying to calculate Levenshtein distance of strings in a column then cluster and label by another column

Tags: r, levenshtein-distance, hierarchical-clustering

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0MTm.png) is a truncated version of my data set. There are many more rows in the full set.
I know I can convert the second column to a vector via as.vector(df[,2]), which I can then use for distance calculation. Once I have the distances, I'm going to cluster. But then I want to know how whether the ones that corresponded to "1" from the first column ended up clustering together, and with "2", "3", and so on. How would I go about that?

Answer (score 0):

It would be more helpful to include a text dump of your data using `dput()`, rather than an image of your data.  It looks like your data might be in Excel.  You could save it as a csv file and load it into R using read.csv with `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`. Then your SecondaryStructure column would be strings.  Once you have that,  load the stringdist package (install if you don't have it). That package has a function called stringdist that will give you a distance matrix using Levenstein distance. Most of the clustering algorithms will take a distance matrix as input.  You might start out with hclust (and maybe better to not use the default `method="complete"` but instead use `method="single"`).  hclust will give you a tree structure.  You will have to use `cutree` to turn that into a set of cluster assignments.   When you have the cluster assignments just use `table(Clusters, PrimarySeqGroup)` to get a confusion matrix.

I hope that this helps.

Comment: "You will have to use cut to turn that into a set of cluster assignments. When you have the cluster assignments just use table(Clusters, PrimarySeqGroup) to get a confusion matrix."
That's what I was looking for. Thanks!
The screenshot was actually from R. I made sure to import it properly :)